# В чем различие Vim и Gvim

Tags: vim

В интернете очень много вижу уроков по `vim` а по `gvim` немного, так вот вопрос в чем различаются эти программы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения обучения ничем. GVim это отдельное графическое приложение запускаемое в отдельном окне. Vim же это приложение запускаемое в терминале.

Answer (score 2):

gVim представляет собой версию Vim, скомпилированную с поддержкой графического
интерфейса. Обычно редактор Vim используют, запуская его в консоли или
эмуляторе терминала. Однако если вы активно используете GUI, вам может быть
полезен gVim. Вот основные возможности:

- Присутствует главное меню программы с часто используемыми командами такими
  как: открыть `:e`, копировать `"+y`, вклеить `"+P`, выделить всё `ggVG`,
  переход к метке `g^]` и другие характерные для обычного редактора.
- Графическая панель инструментов, где также присутствуют команды открытия,
  сохранения файла, есть инструменты поиска и замены, имеется кнопка запуска
  компиляции (см `:help make`).
- Горизонтальные и вертикальные полосы прокрутки.

Особенности:

- Оформление вкладок с использованием графического инструментария (например,
  GTK).
- Расширенная поддержка шрифтов и до 16777216 цветов. Например, ошибки
  правописания (см. `:help hl-SpellBad`) могут подчёркиваться красной или
  синей волнистой линией.
- Используются графические диалоги.

[image: Графическое диалоговое окно «Поиск и замена»]

<sup>Пример диалога замены</sup>

Для этой версии Vim заведены некоторые настройки, начинающиеся с префикса
`gui...`. Основная из них — `guioptions`, которая позволяет задать внешний вид
редактора.

Перед стартом gVim прочитывает свой специальный файл настроек `~/.gvimrc` или
`~/.vim/gvimrc` (это помимо обычного vimrc). Как раз там удобно записать часть
конфигурации, имеющую отношение к GUI.

Запустить эту версию редактора можно командой `gvim` или `vim -g` из
терминала. Полезно создать для этой цели значок в системном меню.

Comment: очень полезная фича в gVim, которой нет в Vim - это настройка межстрочного отступа: например set lsp=8 задает отступ 8 пикселей. В Vim же строки без отступа - читать тяжело. Про шрифты  я бы добавил, что gVim поддерживает *только* моноширинные шрифты.